# “pgAdmin3” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer

Tags: macos, pgadmin

I am new to Mac environment and I am not able to install the "pgAdmin" in the system, the error message it gives is as follows;

> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the Mac
>   App Store and identified developers.
>
> “pgAdmin3” is on the disk image “pgadmin3-1.20.0.dmg”. Google Chrome
>   downloaded this disk image today at 12:21 pm from www.postgresql.org.

Comment: Google "mac os x install unsigned application" or "can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer"

Answer (score 12):

Ctrl-Click, Open.
(That is Ctrl, not Command)